# Haproxy layer 4 tcp-reject source

Tags: tcp, load-balancing, haproxy

Looking for a method to reject tcp connections at layer 4 based on source ip. Couldn't find anything in the haproxy docs, acl exists only at layer 7. Any ideas?

Thank you!